# Coupon code is not validating the customer segment condition on cart page?

Tags: shopping-cart, validation, magento2.4.5, coupon-codes, sales-rule

I have customer segment and sku condition in the cart rule with specific coupon code. This is working fine for sku condition but this is not working for exact customer segment id.

[image]

Same coupon code is applying for other segment id as well.

FYI, for testing purpose I am passing customer segment id hard-coded in vendor to check whether the coupon validation is working or not. But this is not working for customer segment id.

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Show the condition that you set it up for rule.

Comment: @SohelRana, I have added screenshot of rule in question